# JQuery collection array suddenly becomes DOM HTMLDivElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

In my code I have a function that accepts an array of JQuery collections and applies some code to each via a for-loop.

The problem is that as soon as I reference one it somehow becomes a HTMLDivElement instead of a collection object.

```
function vacant_now($timetables, now){
console.log("1:" + $timetables);//still fine
for (var i=0; i < $timetables.length; i++){
    console.log("2:" + $timetables[i]);//problem is here
    var $timetable = $timetables[i];
    console.log("3:" + $timetable);
    $timetable.find(".booking").each(function(){ ...
```

it's called like this:

```
vacant_now($page.find(".timetable"), now);
```

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery collection array is an array of DOM elements.

Doing this: `$('#myDiv')[0];`
returns the same as: `document.getElementByID('myDiv');`

**Solution:**
Use `$('.timetable').eq(index);`

```
for (var i=0; i < $timetables.length; i++){
    $timetables.eq(i);

}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Using [i] on a jQuery object returns the dom element. If you want the jQuery object at a specific index use the .eq() function:

```
console.log("2:" + $timetables.eq(i));
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/8FeEf/1/

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can use the `.each` method, and after you must 'jquerify' the object :

```
function vacant_now($timetables, now) {
    $timetables.each(function() {
        var $timetable = $(this);
    });
}
```

A jquery collection is in fact an array of DOM elements.

You can also use a `for`, the syntaxe is a little bit more verbose.
In all case, you must jquerify the object.

Exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/FTcpD/